# Rails price modification when editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `edit` form that shows a price:

```
<%= form.text_field :price, value: number_to_currency(purchase.price), class: "form-control" %>
```

[image]

When I update the form in the controller I receive:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"wine_item_id"=>"12", "quantity"=>"3",
"price"=>"$12,122.00", "store_attributes"=>#<ActionController::Parameters
{"name"=>"Cuvee 3000"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

But after the update the price becomes:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe that's because when doing "$12,122.00".to_f it results in 0.0. You'll probably have to cast the data received for `price` to fit properly depending on the column datatype.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sebastian-palma, but the format depends of the locale, is there  no standard way to convert back?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no standards for your requirement, you'll have to use your own.

Answer (score 0):

What does console returns, if you type:

WineItem.find(12).price

Is it "$12,122.00" ?

Because it looks to me that you are trying to run to_f on a string, which will result in 0.0

You can check it yourself in irb:

"abc".to_f will equal 0.0